# Dropobx Sync API doesn't update

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm working with the Dropbox Sync API and read in a file from dropbox, when I change the value in this file manually when my app isn't running and I start the app again, the change doesn't come through in my Android app. The value from file.readString() hasn't changed. After I restart my app several times, the changes come through. I tried dbxFs.syncNowAndWait(), file.update() and several other things to make this work. I can't  seem to find the problem, after syncNowAndWait, the dropbox filesystem should "Force a check for new file info from the server" according to the documentation, but this doesn't seem to happen. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();
DbxFile file = dbxFs.open(new DbxPath("Apps/serverIP/serverIP.txt"));
sendIPBroadcast(file.readString().split("\n")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All reads in the Sync API are from cache, and all downloads are asynchronous. So you need to open the file (which will open the cached copy from the last time you ran the app) and register a listener to be notified when a new version of the file has been downloaded. A new version will only be downloaded if you keep the file open. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android#listeners for an example of how to set up a listener.

Comment: I should have said that I already have a listener and this works but only if the file is changed when my app is running. When the value is changed when my app isn't running, I keep working with the old cached value, is there a way to force download?

Comment: The only way to get a download to happen is to open the file and keep the file open. The listener you set up on the file should fire as soon as a new version of the file is cached. (Then you call `update` to be able to read the new version.) If that still doesn't make sense, please share your code for setting up the listener on the `DbxFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by directly downloading the content from the dropbox URL. So I have the content immediately instead of have to wait for the updated content to be downloaded and cached. For further changes, I have a listener running.

```
URL url = new URL("url");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
String ip = getServerResponse(new byte[1], new DataInputStream(ucon.getInputStream()));

private String getServerResponse(byte[] b, DataInputStream in) throws IOException {

    String serverSentence = "";
    while(true){
        in.read(b, 0, 1);   
        String character = new String(b, "UTF-8");
        if(character.equals("*")) break;
        serverSentence += character;
    }
    return serverSentence;
}
```